# Remove from Woocommerce get_customer_location Ajax event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to understand wordpress and woocommerce.
How can I remove the `get_customer_location` HTTP call from my wordpress main page.

Request: https://www.example.com?wc-ajax=get_customer_location

Currently I'm using this source code bellow:

```
function grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner() {

    // Remove the generator tag
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce'], 'generator' ) );
    // Unless we're in the store, remove all the cruft!
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-general');
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-layout' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-smallscreen' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_fancybox_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_chosen_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'selectWoo' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'selectWoo' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-payment-method' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lost-password' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc_price_slider' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'wc-checkout' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-chosen' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'woocommerce' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-blockui' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-placeholder' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-payment' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jqueryui' );        
        wp_dequeue_script( 'cart-widget' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'cart-widget' );      
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-address-i18n-override' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'wc-address-i18n-override' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner', 99 );
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_customer_location` Ajax event is located in [`WC_Ajax` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html) and is triggered by a JS function located in `assets/js/frontend/geolocation.min.js` file.

If you look at [WC_Frontend_Scripts Class file](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Frontend_Scripts.html#270-274), you need to deregister this script using:

```
wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-geolocation' );
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-geolocation' );
```

And make the necessary customizations on a copy of uncompressed `geolocation.js` file before registering it back in Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast replay - it works!